# A better method to implement the alpha synapse function in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, performance

I have implemented a leaky integrate and fire neuron system that gives output in the form of an alpha function `alpha = t/tau * exp(1 - (t/tau))`. However, the piece of code that I use to implement it takes up **atleast 80% of the runtime** (approximately 4s out of the total 5s). During the course of the program this prt gets called at least 30000 times while the `computealphasynapseoutput` function gets called at least 1.5 million times. So I want to reduce the runtime of this part. I have tried using `arrayfun` to implement it but that takes up a lot more time than this.

**Can anyone suggest a more efficient implementation for this code??**

To implement the alpha synapse I used the following piece of code:

```
% Get the identity of the currently active neurons
idAllActiveNeuron = idAllActiveNeuron > 0;
if any(idAllActiveNeuron) % Only run if atleast one neuron is active
    for iActiveNeuron = find(idAllActiveNeuron).' % run for each active neuron
        %% synapticOutputArray stores the synaptic output for each neuron for each time instant
        %% iIntegration is the time instant
        %% spikeTimesArray is a cell array that is composed of spike times for 
        % each neuron. So if I have 5 neurons and neuron 4 spikes twice 
        % while neuron 5 spikes once, spikeTimesArray would be something 
        % like {[], [], [], [0.0023, 0.0034], [0.0675]}
        %% integrationInstant would be a time value like 0.0810
        %% tau_syn stores the value of tau for each neuron

        synapticOutputArray(iActiveNeuron, iIntegration) = computealphasynapseoutput(spikeTimesArray{iActiveNeuron}, integrationInstant, tau_syn(iActiveNeuron));

    end % iActiveNeuron
end
```

The function `computealphasynapse` is implemented as follows:

```
function synapticOutput = computealphasynapseoutput(firingTime, integrationInstant, tauSyn)
%%COMPUTEALPHASYNAPSEOUTPUT Calculates the synaptic output over all
%previous spikes of the neuron at a particular time instant using the
%alpha synapse function
%
% Usage:
%   synapticOutput = computealphasynapseoutput(firingTime, integrationInstant, tauSyn)
%
% Inputs:
%           firingTime: vector of previous firing times (in seconds)
%   integrationInstant: current integration time instant (in seconds)
%               tauSyn: synaptic time constant of the neuron (in seconds)
%
% Output:
%   synapticOutput: Synaptic output of the neuron at current time summed
%                   over all firing instances
%

% Calculate the time difference of firing from current time
timeDifference = (integrationInstant - firingTime) / tauSyn;
% Calculate and sum the synaptic output for each spike
synapticOutput = sum(timeDifference .* exp(1 - timeDifference));

end % computealphasynapseoutput
```

Edit:

> I have finally awarded the bounty for this question to [gnovice](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45027696/7878502)
>   for his awesome answer. It helped me to shave off an entire 40 seconds
>   from my simulation time (from 68 to 28 s). I hope it works for people
>   in the future too. I would also like to acknowledge [MrAzzaman](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44982474/7878502) and
>   [qbzenker](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44997210/7878502) for taking their time to answer the question and
>   teaching me some cool new approaches. Also, others who commented and
>   helped me. Thanks

Comment: Probably not what you are looking for, but have you tried using `parfor` instead of `for`? Your computations are independent, so you might benefit a lot from parallelising.

Comment: I am using parfor for another part of the same program and I cannot have more than 1 of those. So yeah. that is a no go.. Thanks for your suggestion though.

Comment: I have shaved off 10% by reorganising the variables a bit: `synapticOutput = exp(1-integrationInstant/tauSyn)/tauSyn*sum((integrationInstant - firingTime).*exp(firingTime/tauSyn));`. You are probably looking for a qualitative improvement though.. Maybe you could try a C++ implementation, which might be faster than matlab, and then call the C++ from inside Matlab..

Comment: I will try this in my code and see if it helps or not. Thanks

Comment: Can't you precompute `synapticOutputArray` As: `n = numel(idAllActiveNeuron);synapticOutput = cell(1,n);for k = 1:n;timeDifference = (integrationInstant - spikeTimesArray{k})./tauSyn(k); synapticOutput(k) = sum(timeDifference .* exp(1 - timeDifference));end`

Comment: @rahnema1 the `synapticOutputArray` cannot be precomputed as it is part of a neuron network. The value of `spikeTimesArray` updates at every `integrationInstant`. Thanks though

Comment: What sort of values does `tau` typically have? I ask because I'm curious what the typical range of values might be for `timeDifference` (i.e. minimum or maximum expected).

Comment: tau has a value in the range of 10 ms - 20 ms. All the times I have will be in the range between 0 to 1 s with a step size of 0.1 ms (something like `0:0.0001:1`

Comment: what is the max size of `spikeTimesArray` for a given neuron? ie how many times can one neuron spike?

Comment: It could go upto 100 spikes/s sometimes even 200

Comment: So, typically you have around 1100 neurons and you simulate them for about 10000 time steps (0 to 1 second, 0.1 msec time step). Is this about right? How long does this simulation currently take to run?

Comment: @gnovice that's right. I have a 3 layer setup 1st layer 100 neurons, 2nd layer 1000 neurons and 3rd layer 1 neuron. One trial (1 s simulation) typically takes around 10-12 s

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This solution may be a little weird, and very specific to the problem at hand, but *very* efficient. The idea is to reorganize the formula for calculating the summated alpha synapse output in such a way as to minimize the computations done, *specifically* reducing the number of exponentiations computed using [`exp`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/exp.html), which is computationally expensive. Here's the reformulation for a single neuron:

[image]

For the result we have a function of time `f(t)` (that computes one exponential for the current time point `t`) times a linear function in `t` with time-invariant parameters `A` and `B`. Note that `A` and `B` only depend on the spike times, summing an exponential over all previous spike occurrences. We can store these two parameters `A` and `B` for each neuron, and when a new spike occurs in a neuron, we simply compute a new pair of terms and add them to the existing values for `A` and `B`.

Here's the caveat: notice the values of the exponents. For `A` and `B` the value is `ts/tau`, and if it gets too large it could overflow the calculation, resulting in `Inf`. For the parameters we're using here, that won't happen. The value of `ts` will be 1 at its largest (since we're only simulating one second) and the smallest value of `tau` is 0.01 sec. The exponent will be at most 100, giving values that are large (around 10^43), but easily handled by a [`double`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/double.html) variable. Likewise, the exponent in `f(t)` will have a largest negative value of -99, giving very small values (around 10^-43), but still easily handled by a `double` variable without underflowing to 0. However, please bear in mind that using smaller `tau` values or a longer simulation time could cause trouble.

So, how do we implement this? Here are the relevant pieces of code you'll have to add/modify (note that you won't even need `spikeTimesArray` any more):

```
% You'll have to initialize storage for A and B:
A = zeros(1, nNeurons);
B = zeros(1, nNeurons);
idAllActiveNeuron = false(1, nNeurons);

...

% When you are generating new spikes, modify A and B like so:
index = ...;  % A vector of neuron indices where new spikes occur this integration step
if ~isempty(index)
  expTerm = exp(integrationInstant./tau_syn(index));
  A(index) = A(index)+expTerm;
  B(index) = B(index)-integrationInstant.*expTerm;
  idAllActiveNeuron(index) = true;
end

...

% Updating the synaptic output no longer requires a loop:
if any(idAllActiveNeuron)
  synapticOutputArray(idAllActiveNeuron, iIntegration) = ...
    (integrationInstant.*A(idAllActiveNeuron)+B(idAllActiveNeuron)).*...
    exp(1-integrationInstant./tau_syn(idAllActiveNeuron))./tau_syn(idAllActiveNeuron);
end
```

And how well does it do? Here are some measurements I made (using [`timeit`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/timeit.html)) with different average spike firing frequencies for 1101 neurons simulated with a time step of 0.1 msec for one second (10001 time points):

[image]

The more spikes that occurred, the more time it took the original solution to complete. However, the time required for the reformulated solution was near constant and never exceeded 0.6 seconds. I can also confirm that the outputs for the two approaches are equal (maximum differences are on the order of 10^-13 for the synaptic output waveforms).

Comment: This is great @gnovice. Thanks for this. I will try it out and get back to you.

Comment: Finally it worked. I was able to shave off an entire 40 (from 68 to 28 s) seconds off my entire simulation. This was genius. Thanks a lot. You deserve the bounty for this question

Answer (score 2):

I tested the following code with a set of randomly produced firing times and taus, and it consistently ran about 7-8x faster. It's a bit strange, but bear with me.

The main idea is that MATLAB excels at operations on matrices, but can be pretty slow if you have to break those operations up, for instance with your for loop. The idea, then, is to try and do the whole cell array in one go. This would be easier if you could modify how the firing times are stored (i.e., not in a cell array), but I've made do with what you've got.

Basically, what we're going to do is convert the cell array of firing times to one big vector, calculate the synaptic output for all of them at once, then sum them according to their neuron. So, for instance, we'll eventually get the following:

```
% given spikeTimesArray = {[], [], [], [0.0023, 0.0034], [0.0675],...}
firingTimes = [0.0023, 0.0034, 0.0675,...];
neuronInd = [4,4,5,...];
```

where the `neuronInd` vector is the corresponding neuron index of each firing time. This is the vector that, if you could create it when your firing times array was created, this whole process would be that much quicker. As it is, the process to calculate `neuronInd` is a bit opaque.

Regardless, we calculate this as follows:

```
% Calculate the number of time spikes for each neuron
numSpikes = cellfun(@numel,spikeTimesArray);
% Determine the index of all neurons with spikes 
n = find(numSpikes);
% Calculate the starting indices for the neuronInd vector
m = cumsum([1,numSpikes]);
% Generate the neuronInd vector
neuronInd = interp1(m(n),n,1:(m(end)-1),'previous');
% Messy kludge to get around how interp1 works
neuronInd(isnan(neuronInd)) = n(end);
%Calculate timeDifference
delt = ([spikeTimesArray{:}] - integratonInstant)./tau_syn(neuronInd);
synapticOutputArray(:, iIntegration) = accumarray(neuronInd',delt.*exp(1-delt));
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Your approach is very interesting. I tried it in my code but it doesn't work for the following values `spikeTimesArray = {[], [], [], [], [0.0675]}`. The error here is that **Interpolation requires at least two sample points in each dimension**

Comment: Ah, yeah. This would only work if there is more than one spike in the cell array. I also cannot be sure that this will necessarily be more efficient if there are only 5 neurons (I tested it with 10,000-100,000).

Comment: I modified how `neuronInd` is calculated: `neuronInd = arrayfun(@(x) repmat(x, length(spikeTimesArray{x}), 1), 1:length(spikeTimesArray), 'UniformOutput', false); neuronInd = vertcat(neuronInd{:});`. But I am not getting an improvement in times.

Comment: You could replace it with an if statement: `if numel(n)==1;neuronInd=n;else;neuronInd = interp1...` etc. But again, if you've only got a handful of neurons, I don't think this approach will necessarily be faster - I was under the impression there was thousands of neurons.

Comment: There are about 1100 neurons but the same code is rum for them millions of times

Comment: @ammportal and MrAzzaman `neuronInd` can be calculated as `neuronInd = repelem(1:numel(numSpikes),numSpikes);`

Comment: @rahnema1 That's a useful function, I wasn't aware of that! Unfortunately, I'm currently stuck with an older version of MATLAB, so I don't have access to it...

Comment: @rahnema1 `repelem` sounds more like a spell (**Repel 'em**) than a function. I'll try it out in my code. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This code gives me a significant speed up under the right conditions (typically low max number of spike times for any given neuron at a given time and a number of neurons > 5). With a low number of neurons, it is similar to the performance of your code above.

Note that I haven't tested this code with your real inputs so you might have to do some tweaking in order to make it work. Also, it might actually be slower with your data than the dummy data I used. The idea behind the speedup is [`vectorization`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/vectorization.html) --
 essentially doing operations on the entire vector instead of splitting it up over a bunch of for loops.

This will require you to make `spikeTimesArray` a matrix with `NaN`s instead of missing values. So something like this:

```
 spikeTimesArray={[], [], [], [0.0023, 0.0034], [0.0675]}
```

would become

```
spikeTimesArray=[[NaN;NaN], [NaN;NaN], [NaN;NaN], [0.0023; 0.0034], [0.0675;NaN]]
```

and instead of using for loops, you'd just do the entire vector operation:

```
idAllActiveNeuron = idAllActiveNeuron > 0;
if any(idAllActiveNeuron) % Only run if atleast one neuron is active
   % for iActiveNeuron = find(idAllActiveNeuron) % ELIMINATE THIS FOR LOOP

iActiveNeuron = find(idAllActiveNeuron);

timeDifference = (integrationInstant -spikeTimesArray2(:,iActiveNeuron))...
                  ./ tau_syn(iActiveNeuron);

synapticOutputArray(iActiveNeuron, iIntegration) = ...
                                sum(timeDifference .* exp(1 - timeDifference),'omitnan');
```

Note that in this implementation I am assuming that spikeTimesArray2 is an `NxM` matrix where `N` corresponds to the number of maximal spikes for a given neuron and `M` is the total number of neurons. Also, `tau_syn` is a row vector.

Comment: the problem here is that in the last step (when calculating `synapticOutputArray`), the value will be `NaN` for the last neuron. I tried using `nansum` but that is atleast 20 times slower than `sum`. So yeah again no reduction in time. Thanks a lot though. I am beginning to think that what I have is optimum for my usage.

Comment: Sorry - forgot to add the `'omitnan'` flag inside the sum. This for me works almost as fast as `sum`. And agreed - `nansum` is very slow. More generally, I think you have achieved a very fast solution for matlab already. I've done many simulations like this and to get any real performance improvement, going to C/C++ (although there will be some overhead in learning the languages/re-implementing your code) there will likely be a 10-100x speedup in this kind of calculation.

Comment: I tried using your code (with some optimizations). but yeah not much is changing. My code still works atleast twice better for my case. Thanks a lot because I learnt lots of new stuff from both these answers